# JQuery - How to compare the result of a successful $.post

Tags: jquery

the result of the post passes back the value success, i can see this if I alert it out. However, If i try to compare the result by it fails the comparison. What am I doing wrong, How can I compare against the results of a successful post

```
       $.post('ajax.cshtml', data)
                  .success(function (result) {

                      if (result == "success") {
                          alert(result);
                      }

             })
```

Comment: Maybe there is some blank space before or after? Try doing `$.trim(result)` when comparing it.

Comment: I'd suggest adding this line: `console.log('"' + result + '"')` and then look in the debug log to see exactly what the value of `result` is.

Comment: $.trim() didnt work...thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ... and I've never seen .success() before.. isn't is usually .done() that you use with $.post()? The success handler I've only used with $.ajax()

Comment: @entiendoNull - `.success()` is deprecated in favor of `.done()` as of jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$.post('path-to-your-file').done(function(data){
    if($.trim(data) == 'success'){
        alert('success');
        }
    });
```

Or:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'path-to-your-file',
   success: function(data){
        if($.trim(data) == 'success'){
           alert('success');
           }
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the the feedback. Following jfriend00 suggestion, showed there was some whitespace between the apostrophes (Dont know why the $.trim() didnt catch it. For it to work I changed my comparison to

```
                     if (result.indexOf("success") >= 0) {

                      }
```